# What is the benefit of application roles instead of SQL Server authentication in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, security, role

I have a database that is used by an application. This application implements all the business logic and control what a user can do according at its privileges.

I want to avoid users can access to database with another applications like Management Studio, so I have read that I can use application role to only allow to application to access the database.

It seems a good option, but it is needed to store the password in the client application, so I have the problem how to protect this password.

It is the same problem if I use SQL Server authentication. If I use Sql Server authentication, I could create a user MyApplication with a password, and I would have the same problem about how to stored the password. But in practice, I think I have the same functionality than with application role, I have a user with a credentials that nobody knows with the needed privileges to interact with the database, and it is the application who control which actions the user can do.

So in summary, which is the advantage to use application role instead of SQL Server authentication?

Comment: Dupe on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70228112/how-to-handle-permissions-of-an-application-that-access-to-a-sql-server-database

Answer (score 0):

Davis points to a good answer, I just post at a slightly different angle here:

Do you need to keep track of who is doing what, using SQL Server means? Or who is currently connected?

If you are 100% certain that you don't, then it can be fine having all users using the same login.

If that need exist today or perhaps in a near future, you should plan for the users having individual logins. This could be each user having a different SQL login (not fun to administer) or all users having a login which is a Windows group in you AD.

Now you have traceability.

If you don't feel comfortable with above, letting somebody connect using for instance SSMS and play around with the privileges assigned to above login/user, then application role might be for you.

The same (individual) login is used, so traceability exists. But the application calls sp_setapprole passing the password and basically the user context is switched to the one for the app role (you can think of an app role as a user if you want). You will probably make it so that the user context for the app role has higher privilege then the one the one that the "end-users login" is connected to.

Now you have to consider the password management. If you have a fat client, then the password need to be accessible from the machine in one form or another. It might be encrypted, but the key need to be accessible to your app, and through that also your end-user. I.e., it might be *difficult* for your end-user to get the password for the app role, but not technically impossible.

If you have an app server, then of course the app role password can be out of reach for the end-user.